# Undefined method `col_span' for class `Watir::TableCell' (NameError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir

I am fairly new to automation testing and was trying the following code.

While trying to load firefox browser by the following code

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
@browser.goto "https://www.linkedin.com/"

When(/^I enter username as (.*?)$/) do |username|
  @browser.element(:xpath => "//[@id='login-email']").set username
end
....
.... and so on
```

I am getting the following on the first browser load line.

> undefined method `col_span' for class`Watir::TableCell' (NameError)

I am using Ruby (2.5), Cucumber(1.3.2), Watir(4.0.2) and Selenium-webdriver(2.53.4).

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of Watir v6.7, attribute methods are now just the attribute name in lowercase. They are no longer using snake case.

In other words, you want to use `colspan` instead - eg:

```
browser.td.colspan
```

Comment: I just checked, Watir 4.0.2 is being used. This colspan or col_span attribute call must be internal as I am not calling this anywhere. What should I do in the above code to make it work?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use old versions of all of these gems? Cucumber, Watir and Selenium have all had much newer major versions released. With Watir/Selenium using older versions may result in driver incompatibilities (assuming you're running the latest browser versions). I would suggest upgrading first. Then I would suggest providing all of the code you are running so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install only watir instead of watir-webdrive. Then you require watir. When calling the class, use Watir in camelcase. To me it worked this way when calling chromedriver.exe:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
```